# how can I view the installed openerp modules

Tags: odoo

Hi I am using openerp 7 on my XP . I have created a custom openerp module . It was shown in openerp and I installed it successfully but now I dont know where it has been installed. I also cannot view other installed openerp modules . I wanted to see the installed modules . How to view them?

Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

When you said you installed the module, what all you have done? Here are some steps to follow.

1. Create the module (detail on how to create a module is out of scope)
2. copy the module folder in to the addons folder
3. Login in as admin
4. you probably want to see technical details as admin. So, go to "Settings / Users / Users". Open the admin record and edit it. And on access rights tab enable "Technical features". Save the form and reload the page.
5. If the DB is created before the modules folder was copied in to addons, go to "Settings / Modules / Update module list" and Update the module list.
6. Go to "Settings / Modules / Installed module" remove the "installed" filter from search box and search for your module name.
7. Once found the module, click the install button.
8. from  "Settings / Modules / Installed module" find and open the module in form view. Under the "Technical Data" tab, you will see the views added by the module. Under "Features tab" you will all the menus and report created by the module.

Comment: Its ok but I cant see the module within application.

Comment: If you are referring to the module list under "Settings / Modules / Apps" your applications may not be an application by definition on __openerp__.py file.

If you are looking for the menus that are supposed to be created by the module : Go to  "Settings / Modules / Installed module",find and open the module in form view and under "Features tab" check the menus that are created.
Please note that, OpenERP will not create any menu automatically. You have to define them in your xml

Comment: i have created a module but how to define the fields in it . The fields should be like name, project,duration . I just noow wanted to have a form view .

Comment: you have to start from here I guess
https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/03_module_dev/